# Surface integral problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find

$$\int_S yds$$

where $S$ is the part of the plane $$z=1+y$$ that lies inside the cone $$z=\sqrt{2(x^2+y^2)}$$

What I tried to do:

I combine the two equations to get the intersected surface which comes to be:

$$x^2+(y-1)^2/2 = 1$$

Can someone give me a full solution after this (with steps/comments) just to see how it is done.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The unit normal to $S$ is $\frac{(0,1,-1)}{\sqrt2}$ which means that area on the plane is $\mathrm{d}s=\sqrt2\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x$.

The bounds of the region are the intersection of $z^2=(1+y)^2$ and $z^2=2x^2+2y^2$; that is
$$
x^2+\frac{(y-1)^2}2=1\tag{1}
$$
an ellipse with a semi-minor axis of $1$ and semi-major axis of $\sqrt2$.

Thus, the integral is
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^1\int_{1-\sqrt{2-2x^2}}^{1+\sqrt{2-2x^2}}y\,\overbrace{\sqrt2\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x}^{\mathrm{d}s}
&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{2-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-2x^2}}(y+1)\,\sqrt2\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-\sqrt{2-2x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-2x^2}}\,\sqrt2\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
$(2)$ is $\sqrt2$ times the area of the ellipse in $(1)$, which is
$$
\sqrt2\left(\pi\cdot1\cdot\sqrt2\right)=2\pi\tag{3}
$$
That is,
$$
\int_Sy\,\mathrm{d}s=2\pi\tag{4}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Isn't there another way to compute the jacobian and not do the unit normal to S?

Comment: Plus I don't understand the integrals y boundaries

Comment: It is possible to use two unit perpendiculars in the plane, to create a parametrization of the plane, such as $$(x,y,z)=(0,0,1)+u(1,0,0)+v\frac{(0,1,1)}{\sqrt2}$$ and compute the Jacobian $$\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} =\left(\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}\right)^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}^{-1} =\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$$ whose determinant is $\sqrt2$.

Comment: The bounds for the integral simply reflect the bounds given by $(1)$.