# Surface integral of an intersection cone-plane

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

> Find $\iint_S ydS$, where $s$ is the part of the cone $z = \sqrt{2(x^2 + y^2)}$ that lies below the plane $z = 1 + y$

The intersection of these two is an ellipse of area $A = \pi\sqrt {2}$

Note that this problem has been solved here: [Surface integral problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186445/surface-integral-problem). However, I found a slightly different approach.

Let's calculate dS:

$$dS = \sqrt{1 + \frac{4(x^2 + y^2)}{z^2}}dxdy$$

Plugging $z = \sqrt{2(x^2 + y^2)}$ into it you get:

$$dS = \sqrt{3}dxdy$$

Where A = $dxdy = \pi\sqrt {2}$

Then:

$$\iint_S ydS = \sqrt {6}\pi $$

Note this is not the same result robjohn got.

**I don't understand why** $y$ **is treated as it wasn't there.**

I understand the following: $\iint_S dS = \sqrt {6}\pi $

But we have $\iint_S ydS$ and not $\iint_S dS$. I guess there must be a symmetry argument to justify this but I don't see it...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your approach
$$\iint_S ydS =\sqrt{3} \int_A ydxdy=\sqrt{3}\, \bar{y}|A|=\sqrt{3} |A|=\sqrt{6}\pi$$
where $A$ is the interior of the ellipse $x^2+\left(\frac{y-1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=1$, $(\bar{x},\bar{y})=(0,1)$ is its [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#By_integral_formula) (which coincides with its geometric center), and $|A|=\sqrt{2}\pi$ is its area.

Comment: Thanks. I have problems (when solving surface integrals) with the argument of them. Let's say we had for instance $\iint_S xydS$ or $\iint_S y^2dS$. I wouldn't know how to proceed. May you please provide either a quick explanation on how to deal with this or a link?

Comment: We have that $\iint_S f(x,y)dS =\sqrt{3} \int_A f(x,y)dxdy$ then let $X=x$, $Y=(y-1)/\sqrt{2}$ and use polar coordinates. Note that if $f(x,y)$ is $y^2$ or $xy$ the integrals are related with the moments of inertia of the ellipse.